# Why am I not getting any power in two legs of my main power?

Tags: electrical

I have a house that runs solely on 120 volts. For some reason I am only getting 120 volts on one leg on the main power plug going in to my house. The others are not getting any. What could cause this? I only have lights working as well as all but 4 outlets and no hot water heater. It, my house is an old trailer.

Comment: Where is the power fed from?  In a normal house you would suspect there's something wrong with the electric utility and you would want to call them, but if you're tapping power from some other source there's probably a few breakers and/or wires along the way that need to be checked.

Comment: It is coming from a box under my meter.

Comment: Old trailer as in camp trailer or mobile/manufactured trailer/home? If the latter, you should have 240 for dryer, stove, furnace, water heater...unless they are gas appliances. Therefore, you have an issue with possibly something as easy as a breaker.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable doing it, you can take the front panel off of your breaker box and check the voltage of the wires coming in from the meter, but in cases where "one leg is dead" it is usually a problem with the power utility.  In your case it's pretty obvious because you have no 240v loads, but sometimes in houses it can be a confusing and dangerous problem because voltage can travel through a 240v appliance.

I guess it could be a bad connection between the main breaker and the rest of the panel, but we've had several questions on the site about partial power outages and it's generally the power companies issue.

Comment: I have had two service calls for the exact problem; only one of the two legs had power. Power in the other leg was either dead or intermittent. In both cases power was fed from an overhead (not underground) service. And in both cases the dead leg was caused by a short to ground on one of the two main service wires due to contact with a tree branch, but only during windy conditions!

Comment: Had a similar issue.  One leg wasn't fully dead - but it was dying.  Turns out the transformer was melting down.